# Indice fuera de rango en una iteración

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando un programa en el que en cada iteración añade un elemento a una lista. Cuando esta lista tiene 10 elementos o cumpla otra condición, debe eliminar el primer elemento de la lista. Sin embargo, da un error de *index out of range*, ya que se elimina el primer elemento y el índice que busca en la siguiente iteración no existe.

Gracias.

```
if len(list)<=11:
    list.append(3)

for element in range(len(list)):
    if len(list)==10 or otra condición:
           del list[0]
```

Comment: Revisa el código que has pegado. La indentación no es correcta y por tanto no se entiende. Además, quizás lo has simplificado demasiado con respecto a tu problema real, y no se ve claramente qué quieres hacer. Por ejemplo, iteras por una variable llamada `element`, pero no la usas. Además esa variable recorre los índices (pues itera por un `range()`) en lugar de por los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que estás intentando hacer es un tipo de estructura de datos que se llama `Queue` o `Cola`, [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-in-python/) puedes encontrar más información de este tipo de estructura en Python y si deseas leer la documentación del módulo `Queue` puedes mirar [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html).

Una forma bastante simple de hacer una cola es usando el módulo `Queue` de Python, a continuación te muestro la implementación de esta estructura de datos para este problema en particular:

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(maxsize=10)

def add_element(value):

    if(q.full()):
        q.get()
        q.put(value)
    else:
        q.put(value)
    print(list(q.queue))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        add_element(i)
```

Podemos observar como a la cola `q` le asigmanos un tamaño máximo de 10, `q = Queue(maxsize=10)`. En el `if` podemos observar como se hace la comprobación de si la cola está completamente llena, de ser así, se elimina el primer elemento `q.get()` para hacer espacio para el nuevo elemento, inmediatamente después se agrega a la última posición el nuevo elemento `q.put(value)` y en caso de que la cola no esté llena, con el `else` se agrega el nuevo elemento en la posición siguiente al último elemento en la cola, la sentencia `print(list(q.queue))` solo nos imprime en pantalla el estado actual de la cola, sí deseas tener más de una condición a parte de que solo la cola esté llena, se la puedes agregar al `if(q.full() or/and ...)`